# Roll a die until, for the first time, the same side shows up two times in a row. Let $X$ be the number of rolls needed. compute $\mathbb{E}(X)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I'm having trouble with solving this problem:

Roll a die until, for the first time, the same side shows up two times in a row. Let $X$ be the number of rolls needed. compute $\mathbb{E}(X)$.

I know that the answer to this is $\mathbb{E}(X) = 7$, but I don't know why. Could you explain this to me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly different approach using the law of total probability:
\begin{align*}
E(X) ={} & E(X\mid(\text{$(i+1)$-th toss is same as $i$-th})\cdot P(\text{$(i+1)$-th is same}) \\ &{} + E(X\mid(\text{$(i+1)$-th toss is different})\cdot P(\text{$(i+1)$-th is different}) \\
= {} & (2)\cdot\frac{1}{6} + (E(X) + 1) \cdot \frac{5}{6} 
\end{align*}
Then solving for $E(X)$ we have 7.

The important bit to note is that $E(X\mid(\text{$(i+1)$-th toss is different})$ is simply $E(X) + 1$, as you can think of our indicator $i$-th toss "resetting" when we have a different side rolled.

Comment: +1 When it comes to expectations then I really like approaches like this  ;).

Comment: Your answer is the best ;)

Comment: I did some copy-editing on the MathJax code, including proper use of \mid (notice that $P(A|B)$ looks different from $P(A\mid B)$), setting "$i+1$" in math mode rather than text mode and some other small things.  But notice that writing $3*5$ instead of $3\cdot5$ or $3\times 5$ is vulgar. At a state dinner hosted by the Queen at Buckingham Palace you don't eat mashed potatoes with your fingers when silverware is available. Use of an asterisk for ordinary multiplication is for occasions when one is restricted to the characters on the keyboard. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Duly noted, I'm still pretty terrible with MathJax but working at it. Thanks for the edit, I'll keep those points in mind!

Comment: Instead of "$(i+1)$th toss is the same as the $i$th", shouldn't one say "second toss is the same as first"?  After all, getting a number that's appeared before isn't the same as getting a number that appeared only one step earlier, except when there is only one earlier trial. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Doesn't "$(i+1)$th toss is the same as the $i$th" imply that you have got the same number that appeared one step earlier?

Comment: @DonkeyKong : Sorry--- i misread the question: I thought it said simply "two times" rather than "two times in a row". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ahh, no worries. I appreciate the MathJax help and checking out the answer!

Comment: @DonkeyKong : It it had said simply "twice" instead of "twice in a row", then $7$ is the largest it could be, and some quick scratchwork seems to say the average is a bit more than $3.678$, and I'm not very surprised by that number. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3):

Let $Y$ denote the number of rolls that are still needed after the
first roll (so $X=1+Y$).

Then $\mathbb{E}\left(Y\mid Y>1\right)=1+\mathbb{E}Y$ (do you understand
why?) so that

$\mathbb{E}Y=\mathbb{E}\left(Y\mid Y=1\right)P\left(Y=1\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(Y\mid Y>1\right)P\left(Y>1\right)=1+\frac{5}{6}\mathbb{E}Y$

We conclude that $\mathbb{E}Y=6$ and $\mathbb{E}X=1+\mathbb{E}Y=7$.

Comment: I just saw your answer, and it is indeed very similar to mine if not presented a bit differently. I'm rather new here, is it similar enough that you think I should just delete it? My apologies.

Comment: No not at all. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @DonkeyKong I would not delete it (and apologies are really not necessary here).

Comment: @drhab Alright, thanks. Just weary at times of the "first to answer" with slightly different answers (at least coming from Stack Overflow). +1 for a speedy and concise approach ;)

Answer (score 2):

From the second roll onwards, the probability that the roll is the same as the previous one is $1/6$. Therefore the number of rolls until two sides show up in a row is distributed $1+\mathrm{Geom}(1/6)$ (one plus a geometric random variable with success probability $1/6$), whose expectation is $1+6 = 7$.

Comment: @ Yuval Filmus And why is this random variable geometric?

Comment: Peter: it is geometric because constant probability and independent events -> multiplication of probabilities gives a geometric sequence.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of one dice throw to be equal to the previous is constant 1/6, but one previous throw is required to "get started". We would expect to have won once after 6 such tries, but one extra throw is required to get "started".

If you want to calculate it using analysis:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Expected value of the Geometric distribution is 1/p, i.e. 1/(1/6) = 6 in this case and +1 is required to "get started".